# securing stripe secret key with server side

Tags: api, dart, aws-lambda, stripe-payments, aws-amplify

I am just trying to understand how to securely store the stripe secret key.

For sure I should not have it hardcoded on the app.

I am seeing in most tutorials secret value is saved in the server. Then it's retrieved to make call. Can't this be just be simply intercepted?

To make a request like this. This need a secret to passed in. I am using the amplify graphql.

```
 var response = await http.post(Uri.parse('https://api.stripe.com/v1/payment_intents'), body: body, headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer sk_test_51JtrW7EI6WXcFFnPxSxwCIm24D8Gjj3e6hzxch4009kFOsXo7',
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
      });
```

Comment: If you are using AWS (since you used those tags), you can use the secret manager to store it there

Comment: @blurfus really looks a nice option. I am currently using the graphql api. I think this functions based on restapi way. Any references to having it implemented on flutter? Thanks

Comment: If the secret key is stored on the server, then it should act as a proxy between the client and stripe, therefore the client should be calling some function on the server to carry out the request

Comment: @smac89 this secret key based actions should be processed in the server side it self right? The secret key should not be returned by the function?

Comment: That's essentially the idea: client code talks to server code, which talks to stripe

Comment: @smac89 Thanks for clearing it. I was so confused why most of the tutorial returns the stripe keys along the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am seeing in most tutorials secret value is saved in the server. Then it's retrieved to make call.

Most Stripe tutorials show the client-side/webpage/mobile-apps fetching the publishable key from your server. That key is (by design) public.

That approach helps especially with mobile apps where you cannot dynamically update your publishable key, you need to go through a full App Store review to get a new version of your app out, but fetching it from your server allows you to easily update a publishable key if needed.